# How to get leading whitespace in matplotlib labels (legend or xlabel etc.) using latex?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, legend

I would like to insert some leading whitespace into some of my legend labels (problem is the same for other types of labels) with latex turned on. However, any *leading* whitespace that I enter is being ignored (see MWE and image below). An ugly workaround would be to enter a leading `.` (inspired by [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30021162/6135182)). That's not pretty, though.

Any idea how I could get this to work properly? Can it even be done, or should I look into raising an issue with matplotlib?

## MWE:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'cm'

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
plt.plot([], label="~ tilde")
plt.plot([], label="\, comma")
plt.plot([], label="\quad quad")
plt.plot([], label="\hphantom{whitespace} hphantom")
plt.plot([], label=".\hphantom{whitespace} ugly leading dot")
plt.xlabel("\hphantom{whitespace} xlabel")
plt.legend()
```

[image: leading white space in matplotlib legend with latex]

Comment: Hmm, would `\hspace*{1em}` work? If you aren't using transparency, could you use the "ugly dot" with white colour? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9169052/683329

Comment: @sabik Nope, `\hspace*{1em}` (or any hspace) is not working either.

Comment: @sabik I tried fiddling with the textcolor, but using `\usepackage{color}` is a whole other can of worms. The suggestions about changing the textcolor from that Q&A don't work for me, they mess up line spacings.

Comment: I can't test myself, but maybe try `\mbox{}\hphantom{whitespace} ugly leading dot`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Good idea, but nope, `\mbox{}` is being ignored as well... :(

Comment: If the labels are typeset by LaTeX, how comes that they are in a different font from, say, xtick labels? I have checked a different solution, using `\strut`, and it works in LaTeX and it does not in matplotlib. Also, everything else you've tried do work in Latex, do not in Matplotlib.

Comment: @gboffi The different font between tick labels and legend labels, comes down to default settings. I've made the MWE slightly less minimal such that now tick labels and legend labels match. Anyhow, that is unfortunately not what is causing the issue. But, yes, everything I do works in latex but not in matplotlib, which is precisely why I am asking this question...

Comment: Likely it's Matplotlib that, somehow, trims the labels. If you raise an issue, could you please post a link in comments? Tia.

Comment: @gboffi, issue raised on [matplotlib's GitHub page](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24166#issue-1409723459)

Comment: Thank you for the notification, I'm curious…

Comment: It seems one cannot add whitespace, but maybe it is possible to move the text. I managed to do it for ylabel by setting `y=0.4`. For legend texts, it should be more difficult, but maybe still possible.